# Cloud Functions - DDoS protection with max instances cap + node express rate limiter?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, api-gateway, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I've been using Cloud Functions for a while and it's been great so far - though, it seems like there's no builtin way to set limits on how often the function is invoked.

I've set the max # instances to a reasonable number, but for the # invocations, Firebase doesn't really provide a way to set this.  Would using a Node package that limits or slows down requests, when combined with the limited max instances be sufficient to slow down attacks if they happen?

Also know Cloud Endpoints exist - I'm pretty new to OpenAPI and it seems like something that should just be integrated with Functions at an additional cost... but wondering if that would be a good solution too.

Pretty new to all this so appreciate any help!

Comment: Before searching for solution, ask yourselves against what do you want to be protected? If you set a rate limit, is it per user? for all users? If an attacker resquest too many time your Cloud Function, what do you want to perform? Block the IP? revoke the authentication?

Comment: I think it's more for DDoS protection more than anything else.  It would have to be before the request hits cloud functions, because even if it's blocked within functions, the invocation still causes huge billing.

Comment: Do you use private or public Cloud Functions (i mean, do you use the param --allow-unauthenticated to your Cloud Functions?)

Comment: It's public, so we do allow unauthenticated for handling some HTTP calls

Answer (score 1):

If you use only Google Cloud services (I don't know the other cloud provider offers to solve your issue, or even existing framework for this), you can limit the unwanted access at different layer

Firtly, [Google Front End (GFE)](https://cloud.google.com/security/infrastructure/design#google_front_end_service) protects all Google resources (Gmail, Maps, Cloud, Your cloud functions,...) especially against layer 3 and layer 4 common DDoS attacks. In addition, this layer is in charge of the TLS communication establishment, and will also discard the bad connexions.

- Activate the "private mode". This mode forbid the unauthenticated request. With this feature, Google Front End will check if

  - A id_token is present in the request header
  - If the token is valid (correct signature, not expired)
  - If the identity of the token is authorized to access to the resource.

-> Only the valid request reach your service and you will pay only for that. All the bad traffic is processed by Google and "paid" by Google.

- Use a Load balancer with [Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/armor) activated. You can also customize your WAF policies if you need them. Use it in front of your Cloud Functions thanks to the [serverless NEG feature](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/serverless-neg-concepts)
- If you use API Keys, you can use [Cloud Endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/quotas-overview) (or [API Gateway](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway), a managed version of Cloud Endpoint) where you can enforce rate limit per API keys. I wrote [an article on this (Cloud Endpoinr + ESPv2)](https://medium.com/google-cloud/rate-limit-your-api-usage-with-cloud-endpoints-quotas-1270da55d2bf)

Comment: Got it, very helpful!  So it seems like GFE already does some basic work - not sure about Cloud Endpoint (since it seems more expensive per-million-calls than Functions...) and we can't really use private mode since some calls need to be able to be made by unauth'd users.  Will be looking into Cloud Armor + Functions soon though as this seems more applicable!